# Having Trouble Upgrading From Trial

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, upgrade

I have a SharePoint 2010 Trial install, I'm trying to upgrade the license type to Enterprise, but am running into an error and cannot determine any details.

I go to the upgrade and migration section, choose convert farm license type, and enter my license key.  When I submit the page, I receive the error "The product key could not be validated. Check the error logs for details."

1. I looked all throughout my ULS logs, but cannot find any error message.  I see a few references to _admin/conversion.aspx, but no reference to any error messages
2. I restarted IIS, and even the server, but I still receive the same error

Can anyone help?  Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong location for my error logs?  Has anyone run into this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't upgrade from a Trial to an Enterprise license. You need to upgrade to a Standard CAL first, then upgrade that to an Enterprise.

Excerpt from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc263204(v=office.14).aspx:

> You cannot upgrade directly from a Standard trial version to an
>   Enterprise licensed version. You must upgrade to the Enterprise trial
>   version first. Follow the steps in this article to upgrade to the
>   Enterprise trial version and then to the Enterprise licensed version,
>   and then follow the steps in the following article to enable the
>   Enterprise features: [Upgrade from a SharePoint Server 2010 Standard
>   CAL to an Enterprise CAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc261946%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: did you get the trial install to upgrade correctly? Keep us updated!

Comment: Yep!  I had to do just what was mentioned in the article and go from Standard Trial to Standard Licensed, and then Std Lic to Enterprise Lic.